# MySQL Error on Before Trigger for END IF Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

Hello I am trying to write a trigger in mysql and below is my code`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER updateNewEmp
BEFORE INSERT ON employess
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.salary <50000 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    END IF
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But I get an error stating #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF END' at line 7. Could someone please explain what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need a semicolon at the end of the SIGNAL statement.

Comment: I did that too and it says unexpected token ; near

Comment: You really have a table named "employess"?

Comment: Yes I have a table named employess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting semicolons in:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER updateNewEmp
BEFORE INSERT ON employess
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.salary <50000 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000';
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.That does not work either. It still gives me unexpected token ; near . 

Pic: http://tinypic.com/r/oab1fs/9

Comment: @bhuvanesharasu . . . Are you using a rather archaic version of MySQL?

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin. But when I used MySQL workbench this worked. I then figured out that there is something wrong with the phpmyadmin version. Thank you! It worked :)